# Add messages in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using messages in Django.

I've done exactly as told in the documentation and the messages are showing as they should when my site is in production. But in development at cloud9 they are not showing. What could be wrong?

In development it doesn't add the message if I use

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save()
    messages.success(self.request, "Updated")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

but it does add the message if I use

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    messages.success(request, 'Updated')
    return super(ItemUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I don't understand what could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you have added middleware in your settings.py in production stage **'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware'**
and make sure you have imported messages in your views.py.
Also check for **'django.contrib.messages'** in your installed apps

Answer (score 0):

If you want `self.request` you have to override `__init__` method

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

So after that your self.request will work..

Comment: I am adding the messages in my `UpdateView` and not in the form. It is working as it should in production - how does it make sense if I cannot use `self.request` without the code you suggested

Comment: as described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#enabling-messages